# Cant import src/main/java classes into src/test/java jUnit tests in maven-spring-web project. IDE - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I'm working on a maven-spring-web project in Eclipse. I am getting some problem working with jUnit tests, it seems to me a configuration issue.

Project structure:

```
src > main > java : business logic goes here
src > test > java : jUnit test cases are parked here.
```

The trouble is that imports are not working when im trying to import some business logic classes from src>main>java into my jUnit test cases. The reason is that the physical folder structure is :

Business logic classes : `project_root > src > main > java`
Test cases classes : `project_root > src > test > java`

I've tried cleaning, putting testResources directory in POM. I dont want to add classes folder in classpath. Pls advise.

Comment: what is the name of the `original & test class` ?

Comment: com.myapp.AccountDAOImpl and test case is AccountTests

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use default package in src/main/java, try to new a package and you can import the class then.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain why you "can't use default package in src/main/java" in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

By default Maven uses the following naming conventions when looking for tests to run:

- `Test*`
- `*Test`
- `*TestCase`

Your test class doesn't follow these conventions.

Comment: Try to give test name as `AccountDAOImplTest`. Still some problem then let me know.